# Sentry Sourcemaps: bad json: invalid type: map, expected a string

Tags: sentry, source-maps, parcel

I've been tasked with integrating Sentry into our front-end application and I'm having some trouble with it.

After building our source I've set the pipelines to upload our sourcemaps to sentry with:

```
sentry-cli releases -o "myorg" -p "myproject" files "$VERSION" upload-sourcemaps ./
```

This seems to almost work:

```
  DEBUG   2022-12-09 15:18:39.496486472 +00:00 sentry-cli version: 2.10.0, platform: "linux", architecture: "x86_64"
  INFO    2022-12-09 15:18:39.496862713 +00:00 sentry-cli was invoked with the following command line: "sentry-cli" "releases" "-o" "uswitchcom" "-p" "my-mojo-ui" "files" "1.0.1638" "upload-sourcemaps" "./"
> Found 69899 release files
> Analyzing 69899 sources
> Rewriting sources
error: bad json: invalid type: map, expected a string at line 1 column 328
```

The `dist` folder structure is really flat, it's being built with [Parcel](https://parceljs.org/).

```
dist
├── index.0bf95743.js
├── index.0bf95743.js.map
├── index.a11de8bb.js
├── index.a11de8bb.js.map
├── index.fee677fd.css
├── index.fee677fd.css.map
├── index.html
```

(I'm not sure why there's two indexes, the app works fine though)

Any ideas what's wrong? Source maps work in the browser when checking with the debug tools so I can't imagine they'd be broken.